# Remove permission from Team (group) member for specific file (drive item)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When I share a file by chat(P2P) in Microsoft Teams app, the file is stored in the OneDrive , so if I interested to remove permission from a specific user that I sent him the file before, I can do this:
Getting the users that have permissions with this request:

> GET/ https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/permissions

It give me all the users that have the permission,so I choose the one that I want to remove it and use this request:

> DELETE/ https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/permissions/{permissionId}

It's working wonderful.
Now I'm interested to do the same with a file that has shared through a Team in Microsoft Team app.
But when I check the permissions file with this request:

> GET/ https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/permissions
>   It's not return me permissions for each member on the Team.
>   So my question how it is possible to remove file permissions from a specific member on the Team?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[While files shared in a P2P chat are stored in OneDrive, files shared within Team spaces are stored in a SharePoint Document Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sharepoint-onedrive-interact). Permissions on the SharePoint document repository are *group* based, and use the Azure AD group for the Team. If you want to remove an individual's permissions for files shared to a Team, they would need to be removed from the group (which would remove their access to everything *else* for the Team as well).

Comment: Thanks, but my question was if it is possible to remove only the permission for the file , not removed the user from the Team. From what you say I understand that it is not possible.

Comment: That is correct, it is not possible to remove an individual's permissions to a file because files shared in Teams spaces are permissioned by group and not individual user.